# put dots/small circles in each corner of each cell in a table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically I want to achieve something like this. Can somebody please tell me how this can be done and what is the best way to make it mobile compatible.
Thank you
[image]

Comment: Can you post your current HTML & CSS code so that we can understand what you have already achieved?

Comment: I've got nothing yet. I was hoping to figure out a way how to do this before doing any coding

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using pseudo css selectors such as: `first-child`, `last-child`, etc, you can use table or whatever html tag you want, this is an example:

```css
.o-table{
    .o-table__head{
    th{
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid green;
      &:first-child{
          border-left: 0;
          border-top: 0;
          &:after{
            content: "";
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 4px;
            height: 4px;
            background-color: green;
            position: absolute;
            top: -1px;
            right: -1px;
        }
      }
      
      &:last-child{
          border-right: 0;
          border-top: 0;
          &:after{
              content: "";
              border-radius: 50%;
              width: 4px;
              height: 4px;
              background-color: green;
              position: absolute;
              top: -1px;
              left: -1px;
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="o-table">
    <thead class="o-table__head">
        <tr>
            <th>col 1</th>
            <th>col 2</th>
            <th>col 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="o-table__tbody">
        <tr>
            <td>row 1</td>
            <td>row 1</td>
            <td>row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row 2</td>
            <td>row 2</td>
            <td>row 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```